# How does the return value "res" is updated? (ConcativeMat Con NN)

Tags: c++, loops, opencv, concatenation, convolution

I have a questions about a for loop and its return value. This is C++ code, and I'm using openCV 2.4V.

Input to this function is max value of 600 images with pooling. 
600 images << pooling << max value points. 
The size of "res" matrix is 600x128 and vec.size() = 600.

For me, within the for loop, the res never get updated, however return value is not zeros.

I suspected

"ptmat.copyTo(subView)"

because, I thought that is not necessary line. However when I took that out, res did not get updated(being zero like initial Mat). Can anybody explain how does the res value get updated?

Also why does this function is called concatenate..?

```
 Mat
 concatenateMat(vector<vector<Mat> > &vec) {

    int subFeatures = vec[0][0].rows * vec[0][0].cols;
    int height = vec[0].size() * subFeatures;
    int width = vec.size();
    Mat res = Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_64FC1);

    for (int i = 0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<vec[i].size(); j++) {
            Rect roi = Rect(i, j * subFeatures, 1, subFeatures);
            Mat subView = res(roi);
            Mat ptmat = vec[i][j].reshape(0, subFeatures);
            ptmat.copyTo(subView);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id6), the Mat::operator() does not make a copy of matrix data, thus any change to **subView** matrix object in the loop will be reflected in **res** matrix object as well. That's the line you've mentioned:

```
ptmat.copyTo(subView);
```

---

It's called concatenate because it concatenates 2D vector of Mat objects into a single one.